# Wiring Combination Switch GFCI Outlet

Tags: gfci, receptacle

I [read](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/how-should-i-wire-a-gfci-outlet-and-a-switch-to-isolate-the-switch-but-provide-g) [some](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62423/change-gfci-outlet-switch-with-regular-switch) [related](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/upgrade-from-outlet-switch-combo-to-gfci-outlet) [questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40359/gfci-combination-switch-and-outlet-to-fully-switched-protected-outlet), but can't find an answer given my wiring. I'm trying to wire a combination switch/GFCI outlet [Pass & Seymour 1595SWTTRWCC4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DZQ884). I also checked the [wiring](http://www.legrand.us/~/media/products/resources/pass-and-seymour/Instruction%20Sheets/340737.ashx) [diagrams](http://www.legrand.us/~/media/products/resources/pass-and-seymour/Instruction%20Sheets/340557.ashx), and none of them match my wiring (two red line wires)...

Here's the wiring of the gang receptacle:

[image]

Here's how the combination switch/GFCI outlet looks:

[image]

Here's how another switch is wired **without** two red line wires:

[image]

Here's where I'm stuck. Where do the two red line wires go? My guess is in the Hot Line?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How was the previous device wired? I'm guessing one of the red/white pairs is the line (from the panel), and the other set is a feeder to the rest of the circuit. You'll have to determine which set is the feeder from the panel, and where the other set goes and whether or not you want to GFCI protect it.

Comment: @Tester101 The only thing I recall about the previous combination switch outlet wiring was that the two red wires were both on the `+ LINE +` side of the outlet

Comment: Then you should connect them both to the line side hot terminal of this device as well.

Comment: Why are you installing a GFCI device?

Comment: Sounds like [this is what you want](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g26sz.jpg).

Comment: @Tester101 This is a 1/2 bath; next to a sink, so it won't pass inspection when we sell. I will try that.

Comment: @Tester101 Works great. Would you like to make it answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing one of the red/white pairs is the line (from the panel), and the other set is a feeder to the rest of the circuit. You'll have to determine which set is the feeder from the panel, and where the other set goes and whether or not you want to GFCI protect it.

If this is true, you should connect them both to the line side hot terminal of this device as well.

[image: correct wiring]

**Edit** - Picture of end result

[image]